# Expectation of a fractional form of chi squared

Tags: normal-distribution, quadratic-form

I have been trying to calculate or find a result for the expectation
$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{w^\top D^2 w}{1 + w^\top D w}  \right] $$
where $$w \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_N),$$
and $D$ is a diagonal matrix of size $N$.

As a matter of fact, I could not even find a result on the expectation
$\mathbb{E} \left[ x^2 / (1+x^2) \right]$ where $x\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Is it indeed the fact that these quantities were not studied before or impossible to get closed form solutions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $x^2=q$ with $q$ following a chi-square distribution with one degree of freedom we want to calculate

$$E\left(\frac {q}{1+q}\right) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac 1{\sqrt {2 \pi}}q^{-1/2}e^{-q/2}  \frac {q}{1+q}{\rm d}q  = \frac 1{\sqrt {2 \pi}}\int_0^{\infty}q^{1/2}(1+q)^{-1}e^{-q/2} {\rm d}q \;(1)
$$

In **Gradshteyn & Ryzhik** 7th ed., eq. **3.383**(6), p. 348, we find that

$$\int_0^{\infty}q^{v-1}(\beta+q)^{-v+1/2}e^{-\mu q} {\rm d}q = 2^{v-1/2}\Gamma(v)\mu^{-1/2}e^{\beta\mu/2}D_{1-2v}(\sqrt{2\beta\mu})$$

where $D_v(x)$ is Whittaker's parabolic cylinder function.

This expression matches our integral if we set

$$v =3/2,\;\beta =1,\;\mu =1/2$$
and we obtain

$$E\left(\frac {q}{1+q}\right) = \frac 1{\sqrt {2 \pi}}\cdot 2\cdot \Gamma(3/2)\cdot \sqrt{2}\cdot e^{1/4}D_{-2}(1)= e^{1/4}D_{-2}(1) \tag{2}$$

In the same book we find (**9.254**(2), p. 1030) (note that G+R use the symbol $\Phi$ to refer to the Error function)

that

$$D_{-2}(1) = e^{1/4}\sqrt {\frac {\pi}{2}}\cdot \left[\sqrt{\frac {2}{\pi}}e^{-1/2}-\left(1-{\rm erf}(1/\sqrt 2)\right)\right]$$

where ${\rm erf}()$ is the Error function, which connects with the standard normal CDF $\Phi()$,${\rm erf}(x/\sqrt 2) = 2\Phi(x)-1$ , so

$$D_{-2}(1) = e^{1/4}\sqrt {\frac {\pi}{2}}\cdot \left[\sqrt {\frac {2}{\pi}}e^{-1/2}-\left(1-2\Phi(1) +1\right)\right] $$

$$ = e^{-1/4} -e^{1/4}\sqrt {\frac {\pi}{2}}\cdot 2\Phi(-1) \tag {3}$$

Inserting $(3)$ into $(2)$ we get

$$E\left(\frac {q}{1+q}\right) = 1 - \sqrt {2e\pi}\cdot\Phi(-1) \approx 0.344320458 \tag {4}$$

A quick simulation verifies this. Using $500,000$ draws
$$\begin{align}\\
  \text{Mean  }      &                  0.34433\\
  \text {Median  }     &                 0.31252\\
  \text{Minimum  } &             4.1420e-013\\
  \text{Maximum  }       &              0.96302\\
  \text{Standard deviation  }   &       0.26461\\
  \text{C.V.  }          &              0.76848\\
  \text{Skewness  }     &              0.31389\\
  \text{Ex. kurtosis  }   &            -1.1778\\
  \text{5% percentile  }   &         0.0038428\\
  \text{95% percentile  }   &           0.79284\\
  \text{Interquartile range  }  &      0.47709\\
\end{align}$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the result and also for the source. This definitely matches my simulations too. Now I have a starting source for studying the other case. I really appreciate your knowledge.